# Finding odds of a prize draw

Tags: probability

Im trying to establish 3 separate odds for the same equation. Lets use a draw for an example. 200,000 people enter a draw, there are 3 top prizes lets say for example

1st prize $1m,

2nd prize $500k

& 3rd prize $250k.

I understand that each draw/ticket has a 1/200,000 chance of winning 1st prize hence $1m but what are the odds of winning the 2nd and 3rd prize. Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odds of a particular ticket winning second is also $1/200,000$ and the same for any ticket winning third.  You can confuse yourself by thinking that one ticket has already been drawn for first prize but it doesn't matter.  You might as well draw for second prize first and each ticket clearly has $1/200,000$ chance of winning second.